# Virtual attributes for embedded model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

is it possible to have virtual attributes for embedded models?

I have a class A:

```
class A
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String

  embedded_in :b

  def pnl=(p)
  end
  def pnl
    "p"
  end

  def as_json(options={})
     attrs = super(methods: [:pnl])
     attrs
  end
end
```

and class B:

```
class B
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String

  embedds :a
end
```

If I take a record from B:
    b = B.first
    b.as_json

I dont get the virtual attributes from embedded class a - I only see the persistent attributes. My controller is supposed to return b inclusive all virtual attributes of their embedded objects - but this doesnt work.

If I do:
   b.a.as_json

Then I get the virtual attributes of embedded class A but this doesnt help. If I do not use embedded but referenced relationship (belongs_to/ has_one) it works all fine, but I thought embedded relationship would be better for my use case.
CORRECTION: It also doesnt work with referenced relationship. It seems virtual attributes are not supported for any relationship?

Is there a way I also get the virtual attributes calling b.as_json?

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

seems as_json doesnt recursivle call as_json. The solution is to overwrite serializable_hash instead of as_json and it works as expected. Not sure what is the reason it doesnt work with as_json.

Rgds
Michaek